# Count how many objects was "visibile" (they are visible during a range of dates) for every month in the last years

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this Shop collection

```
var schema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
    },
...

    created_at: {
        type: Date,
    },
    lost_at: {
        type: Date,
    },
}
mongoose.model("Shop", schema);
```

Assuming that a Shop is "**visible**" only during the period between the created_at and lost_at dates.

I would like to have this result:

```
[{ _id: null, year: '2023', month: '2', count: 0 },
{ _id: null, year: '2023', month: '3', count: 3},
{ _id: null, year: '2023', month: '4', count: 8},
{ _id: null, year: '2023', month: '5', count: 16}
...]
```

Where:

- year and month are all the years and months of the last 5 years, even if no Shops have created_at or lost_at corresponding to that month.
- count is the number of Shops "**visible**" in that month.

I solved the problem using a nodejs task with two different aggregations.

But I would like to have this data in a mongodb charts so I need a single aggregation.

Comment: What are the two aggregations that you used successfully?

Comment: @user20042973 One aggregation groups the shops by the date of created_at, the other by date of lost_at. Then in Nodejs I calculate for every month how many created and how many lost shops I have. I can share the code if needed